# Trying to analyze text and sentiments

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to analyze text and sentiment data, but I don't want an extensive analysis. I just want a basic distribution of good, neutral and bad, and the percentage of each category.

can anyone direct me with some advice or suggestions?

thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WinkNLP](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-nlp) can measure sentiment on a scale of -1 to +1 for the entire document or its sentences. Here is an [Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@winkjs/how-to-perform-sentiment-analysis?collection=@winkjs/winknlp-recipes) with a live example.